# d3js - my line graph not working, and throws error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I am drawing a chart using an array of object. but I am not getting any output. as well i am getting the error as `Uncaught TypeError: string.slice is not a function` - But i don't know from where this issue comes.

any one please help me to fix this issue?

here is my code and demo :

```
window.onload = function () {

var data = [
{"date":20111001,"New York" : 63.4, "San Franscisco" : 62.7, "Austin" : 72.2 },
{"date":20111002,"New York" : 58.0, "San Franscisco" : 59.9, "Austin" : 67.7 },
{"date":20111003,"New York" : 53.3, "San Franscisco" : 59.1, "Austin" : 69.4 },
{"date":20111004,"New York" : 55.7, "San Franscisco" : 58.8, "Austin" : 68.0 },
{"date":20111005,"New York" : 64.2, "San Franscisco" : 58.7, "Austin" : 72.4 },
{"date":20111006,"New York" : 58.8, "San Franscisco" : 57.0, "Austin" : 77.0 },
{"date":20111007,"New York" : 57.9, "San Franscisco" : 56.7, "Austin" : 82.3 },
{"date":20111008,"New York" : 61.8, "San Franscisco" : 56.8, "Austin" : 78.9 },
{"date":20111009,"New York" : 69.3, "San Franscisco" : 56.7, "Austin" : 68.8 },
{"date":20111010,"New York" : 71.2, "San Franscisco" : 60.1, "Austin" : 68.7 }

]

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(["New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"])
      .range(["#FF0000", "#009933" , "#0000FF"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach( function ( data, value) {


  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.date = parseDate(data.date);

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: data.date, temperature: +data[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");


  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

})

}
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/P8s8djMAEVvb9fq9PlpD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because

In the data you are passing

```
{"date":20111001,"New York" : 63.4, "San Franscisco" : 62.7, "Austin" : 72.2 },
```

Please note date here you passing date as a number example:**20111001**

So when you parse it to Date object you should convert it into string.

```
data.date = parseDate(data.date + "");
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KsDuZE6gzj57B0n4lfaJ?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Other problem is that you are doing unrelated stuffs in the for loop.

Where as the for loop is just meant for converting the number date into date object, like this:

```
datas.forEach( function ( data, value) {
  data.date = parseDate(data.date + "");
})
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GY8RaLAe7uj9z8cSDqgK?p=preview)

Comment: yes, the error is went off. but still I am not getting any out put. can you please help me further?

Comment: Cyril, I am waiting to get your help.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do here you have a date and some values against cities but dont know what you want to make

Comment: getting updated from your ideas, I have made my first line chart. but I would like to keep the 'city` name as `x` axis values instead of numbers. how to do that? here is my try : http://plnkr.co/edit/7PNd8BOmyut88X5bavj3?p=preview